# Building a model on Keras correctly

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm new to neural networks and Keras, and I want to build a CNN that predicts certain values of an image. (the three values predict the size, length, and width of a blur put on top of the image). All 3 values can range from 0 to 1, and I have a large data set.

I am not exactly sure how to build the CNN to do this though, as all the prototype codes that I have built so far give me predictions of the format `[1.,0.,0.]` instead of ranges between 0 and 1 for each value. On top of that, despite changing the number of epochs and decay value in the SGD optimizer, I don't get any change in my loss function at all. Can you please tell me where I am going wrong? Here is what I have so far:

```
images, labels = load_dataset("images")   # function that loads images
images = np.asarray(images) # images are flattened 424*424 arrays (grayscale)
labels = np.asarray(labels) # Lables are 3-arrays, each value is float from 0-1

# I won't write this part but here I split into train_imgs and test_imgs

model = keras.Sequential()
# explicitly define SGD so that I can change the decay rate
sgd = keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)

model.add(keras.layers.Dense(32, input_shape=(424*424,) ))
model.add(keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',optimizer=sgd)
# note: I also tried defining a weighted binary crossentropy but it changed nothing

checkpoint_name = 'Weights-{epoch:03d}--{val_loss:.5f}.hdf5' 
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(checkpoint_name, monitor='val_loss', verbose = 0, save_best_only = True, mode ='auto')
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]

model.fit(train_imgs, train_labls, epochs=20, batch_size=32, validation_split = 0.2, callbacks=callbacks_list)

predictions = model.predict(test_imgs) # make predictions on same test set!
```

Now I know that I am leaving out dropout layers, but I WANT the CNN to overfit my data, at this point I just want it to do anything. When I predict on the same set of images, I would hopefully get exact results, no? I'm not quite sure what I'm missing. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing, is replacing `'softmax'` with `'sigmoid'`.

Sigmoid will make the three outputs range from 0 to 1. Also notice that softmax is made for classification. It tries to maximize only one of the three values, and the sum of the three will always be one.

Second, if your loss is completely frozen, the problem may be in `'relu'` (relu has a constant zero region where there is not gradient). You can either replace the `'relu`' with another thing such as a `'sigmoid'` or a `'tanh'`, or you can also add a `BatchNormalization()` layer before the relu.

As a begginer choice, I always prefer using the `optimizer='adam'`, this is very often way faster than SGD and you don't need to care much about the learning rate (of course advanced models and best results might take adjustmentes).

Comment: That seemed to do the trick! You're right about relu as well, I was getting stuck in the dead zone and didn't even realize it. Thanks a lot for the help!!